# Using Sorting Layers with 3-d meshes

Tags: unity, layers, sorting

I have 3 layers of objects in a game that I am working on. The layers are the "map" layer (Background), "UI" layer (Labels, etc), and the "Object" layer (Movable objects). I am working on a 2-D game, although I'm using 3-d meshes to give shadow effects. I've used sorting layers, but I can't get the objects to render in the correct order. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

The UI objects are placed on a world space canvas.

What I'm seeing now:

[image]

This is a Scene View, rendered in 3-d

[image]

The "Ship" is the only object in the sorting layer "Object" (Object hiding underneath "Guadeloupe" text".

[image: Label Canvas]

Sorting Layers

[image]

Any thoughts how to make this work? I would like to keep the objects where they are, due to shadow reasons, if at all possible. Thanks!

Comment: What is the "correct order" you want? It seems just fine in screenshots.

Comment: I want the label to be behind the ship.